# vim tmux backspace ^?

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm having a strange problem:

When sshing into a particular host (from OSX to RHEL5), vim seems to forget how to backspace, but only in a tmux session, ie:

```
  ssh foo@bar.com
  vim test
```

Backspace works fine above.

This doesn't however:

```
  ssh foo@bar.com
  tmux
  vim test
```

Hitting backspace in insert mode produces ^?  What could the problem be?

Comment: Does pressing `Ctrl-H` work? If so, check out [this setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2hu3G.png) (focused) in Terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately im using iterm2 :)

Comment: Ctrl+H doesn't work for me =/ still gives same `^?`

Answer (score 5):

You might need to change your Terminal to send `^h` when you type `Backspace`.

In Terminal's preferences, the setting is part of the profile, so you can set up a dedicated profile for your SSH connection to that RHEL5 system.

[image]

Comment: and how to change terminal in TMUX? i'm cygwin now and actually in cygwin this works fine, ssh'ing to rhel6.4 vim gives this problem, fixed term in vimrc, problem fixed, but in tmux it's still gives me the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can map the backspace key to what you need, like Kevin said. It looks like you need to map it to ^? (rather than ^H)

To do that, use the following command:

```
stty erase "^?"
```

This can be added to your startup scripts (`.login` or `.tcshrc` or `.bashrc`, or other files, depending on which shell you use).

Answer (score 1):

To fix backspace on Apple M1 Pro OSX 12.4
I had to do this

```
$(brew --prefix)/opt/ncurses/bin/infocmp tmux-256color > ~/tmux-256color.info
tic -xe tmux-256color ~/tmux-256color.info
```

Issues:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1257#issuecomment-581378716

https://gist.github.com/bbqtd/a4ac060d6f6b9ea6fe3aabe735aa9d95

Answer (score 0):

I find giving this command

> stty erase <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>

works for me. However, I need to do this on every pane.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround

1. Make an alias in `.alias`

   ```
   alias emacs(or vi)='stty erase "^H"

   emacs'
   ```
2. Make a shell script

   ```
   # filename tmuxsh

   stty ek
   cmd=$(which tmux)      # tmux path
   session=$1
   if [ $# = 0 ]; then
      $cmd ls
      exit 0
   fi
   $cmd has -t $session 2> /dev/null
   if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        $cmd new -s $session
        exit 0
   fi
   $cmd att -t $session
   exit 0
   ```

Of course, you could make an alias too,  `alias tm=tmuxsh`.
then you could use emacs/vi both in tmux or out of tmux well.

Why make an emacs alias in step 1? Because if just use step 2, after quit tmux to normal shell, the emacs/vi will encounter the issue too.

It works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xshell like me,try to change Backspace from [Backspace(Ctrl+H)] to [ASCII 127(Ctrl+?)].
In my case, backspace works again in both bash\zsh\tmux+zsh.
This problem has nothing to do with $TERM variable.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6y82.png]